# Python script being stopped after a subprocess is completed

Tags: python, subprocess

When running my script, I am running a set of for loops dynamically. Basically calling a list of items, checking to see what 'stage' that item needs to be ran in, and then running them all in that order. When I am trying to run these loops, it gets through the first object, and then gives a "[1]+ Stopped        Script.py" in the terminal. I have found ways to start back up my script, but no post about how to avoid this happening entirely.

I have tried using `Popen`, `call`, `check_output`, etc. They all get the same result. I am sure it is the other item I am calling that is doing this at the end of it, but I do not think that another program closing out should kill my script, especially not in a subprocess.

I have also tried using threading and multiprocessing. Both to no avail.

```
def foo(list):
    stages = 0
    for c in things:
        info = load_json_info(c)
        if info["stage"] >= stages:
            stages = info["stage"]
    for p in list:
        use_list(p)
    stages = stages + 1
    for i in range(stages):
        for b in list:
            info = load_json_info(b)
            if info["stage"] == i:
                if info["check"] != "NO":
                    output = call("command", shell=True)
                    if output == 0:
                        DO_THING()
                    else:
                        DONT_DO_THING()
                else:
                    DONT_DO_THING()
```

It gets to the `DO_THING()` and goes through all of that, then when it comes time to call another subprocess it dies out again. Whether that subprocess lives in `DO_THING()` or I comment everything out and just get it to hit the `output = call("command", shell=True)` line again. As soon as it goes to use subprocess again it stops.

Any suggestions or ways people have found to block whatever is being passed to stop my script?

(Just as a heads up, I do not have access to the source of the `"command"` that is causing my script to stop, and the `"command"` I am using is not important since I can not do anything on that end. I must use this `"command"` as well.)

Comment: Are you getting an error message in your python?  Are you sure that something isn't blocking the commnad from running again, so your script just flies through the list and ends?

Answer (score 0):

The message you see indicates that your subprocess is being *stopped*, not that there is an error. This happens for example when typing `Ctrl-Z` after starting a process in the shell, or equivalently, sending the target process the `SIGTSTP` signal using the `kill` command. Presumably, the `command` to which you don't have access is receiving this signal. It could even be sending it to itself, although without knowing more about the command it's just speculation as to how or why that's happening.

You can choose to *ignore* this signal in Python by using the `signal` module, specifically the `pthread_sigmask()` function. One specifies a mask of signals, and what to do about them. In this case, you want to ignore the `SIGTSTP` signal, which an be done with: `signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_BLOCK, (signal.SIGTSTP,))`. (The latter argument is actually a sequence of signals to ignore.)

Running this snippet of code, you should see that you can type `Ctrl-Z` in the terminal, and the shell should show `[1]+ Stopped ...`:

```
import time
duration = 5.0
print('Sleeping for {:0.2f} seconds'.format(duration))
time.sleep(duration)
```

However, using the following code, one will see that the signal is ignored, and the process will continue to "work" (sleep, in this case) regardless of the signal. You should just see `^Z` at the shell whenever you press `Ctrl-Z`.

```
import time
import signal
duration = 5.0
print('Sleeping for {:0.2f} seconds, ignoring SIGTSTP'.format(duration))
signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_BLOCK, (signal.SIGTSTP,))
time.sleep(duration)
```

To actually use this in your script, ignore the signal before you call the relevant `command`. It is good practice to query a process's signal mask beforehand, and reset it to that value after you're done with `command`. You should look at the man pages for `signal(3)`, `sigprocmask(2)`, and `kill(2)` for more information about signals and processes.

**Edit for Python <= 2.7**

`signal.pthread_sigmask` was added in Python 3.3. A solution that should work for earlier versions is to directly ignore the signal, by installing a handler which does just that. For example:

```
import signal
import time

duration = 5.0
signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, signal.SIG_IGN)
print 'Sleeping for %f seconds, ignoring SIGTSTP' % duration
time.sleep(duration)
```

As with the 3.3 example above, you should just see `^Z` if you hit `Ctrl-Z`, indicating that the signal was ignored.

Comment: Sadly, I am running 'Python 2.7.10'. Too deep into this project to upgrade it now. Do you know of a way that could work pre 3.3?

Comment: @Kakuga Added an edited version that should work for 2.7.